# Postgres trigger that backs up deleted records for given table + deleted_at timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I have this PostgreSQL trigger that creates in a backup-table a record every time a record is deleted from a given table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE records (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone
);

CREATE TABLE backup_records (LIKE records, deleted_at timestamp);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION backup_records() RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I values($1.*, NOW())', 'backup_' || TG_TABLE_NAME) USING old;
        RETURN OLD;
    END;
$$;
```

This works as intended, fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/dUMhOsoS

However, this function assumes that the `deleted_at` column is always the last one and this might change in the future if the tables get columns added to it.

So I'm trying to modify the function to first get the list of columns from `information_schema` and use it in the insert statement:

```sql
create or replace function backup_records() returns trigger
  language plpgsql
  as $$
DECLARE column_names varchar;
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO column_names STRING_AGG(column_name, ',')
    FROM information_schema.columns where table_name = TG_TABLE_NAME;

    -- RAISE NOTICE 'Value: %', column_names;

    EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I($1, deleted_at) VALUES($2.*, NOW())', 'backup_' || TG_TABLE_NAME) 
      USING column_names, OLD;
    return OLD;
END;
$$;
```

However, this results in the following error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO backup_records($1, deleted_at) VALUES($2.*, NOW(...
```

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/vAvswHJ0

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks, I figured it out in the meantime. Feel free to post it as an answer so I can accept ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a parameter for the column list. Use `string_agg(quote_ident(column_name, ','))` to avoid SQL injection, then use `%s` to interpolate that string into the statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION backup_records() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$DECLARE
   column_names text;
BEGIN
   SELECT string_agg(quote_ident(column_name), ',') INTO column_names
   FROM information_schema.columns
   WHERE table_name = TG_TABLE_NAME;

   EXECUTE format(
              'INSERT INTO %I(%s, deleted_at) VALUES($2.*, NOW())',
              'backup_' || TG_TABLE_NAME,
              column_names
           )
           USING OLD;

   RETURN OLD;
END;$$;
```